# Recursive find in tree

Tags: scala

I have tree structure like below

```
  case class Node(val entity : Entity, val children : Seq[Node])
  case class Entity(val key : String)
```

I wrote below functions to filter nodes based on key

```
  def findPredicate(search: String, entityNode: Node): Boolean =
    search == entityNode.entity.key || entityNode.children.exists(r => findPredicate(search, r))

  def findSubTree(searchKey: String,  entityNode: Node): Option[Node] = {
    val key = entityNode.entity.key
    searchKey match {
      case `key` => Some(entityNode)
      case _ => entityNode.children.find(r => findPredicate(searchKey, r)).
        flatMap(resp => findSubTree(searchKey, resp))
    }
  }
```

It is working fine so far, test cases

```
  val nodes: Node =
    Node(Entity("o1-01"), Seq(
      Node(Entity("o2-01"), Seq(
        Node(Entity("b-01"), Seq(
          Node(Entity("w-01"), Seq.empty),
          Node(Entity("w-02"), Seq.empty)
        ))
      )),
      Node(Entity("o2-02"), Seq(
        Node(Entity("b-02"), Seq(
          Node(Entity("w-03"), Seq.empty),
          Node(Entity("w-04"), Seq.empty)
        )),
        Node(Entity("b-03"), Seq(
          Node(Entity("w-05"), Seq.empty),
          Node(Entity("w-06"), Seq.empty)
        ))
      ))
    )
    )

  print(findSubTree("o2-01", nodes) + "\n") //Some(Node(Entity(o2-01),List(Node(Entity(b-01),List(Node(Entity(w-01),List()), Node(Entity(w-02),List()))))))
  print(findSubTree("b-01", nodes) + "\n") //Some(Node(Entity(b-01),List(Node(Entity(w-01),List()), Node(Entity(w-02),List()))))
  print(findSubTree("w-01", nodes) + "\n") //Some(Node(Entity(w-01),List()))
  print(findSubTree("w-02", nodes) + "\n") //Some(Node(Entity(w-02),List()))
  print(findSubTree("b-02", nodes) + "\n") //Some(Node(Entity(b-02),List(Node(Entity(w-03),List()), Node(Entity(w-04),List()))))
```

1. I want to extend `findSubTree` function with multiple search keys and list of entityNodes as return value

`def findSubTree(searchKey: Seq[String],  entityNode: Seq[Node]): Option[Seq[Node]]`

2. I am traversing tree 2 times already in current solution. Is there any better way to find/filter nodes based on multiple keys?

Comment: I wrote below code to filter which can take any filter...  def filterNodes(
    rootNodes: Seq[Node],
    filterFunc: Node => Boolean
  ): Seq[Node] = {
    val result = rootNodes.flatMap { node: Node =>
      val filteredChildren = filterNodes(node.children, filterFunc)

      if (filterFunc(node)) Seq(node.copy(children = filteredChildren))
      else filteredChildren
    }

    result
  }

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using [`Stream`](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/concrete-immutable-collection-classes.html#streams).  It recurses until it finds a match.

```scala
def findSub(n: Node, k: String): Stream[Node] =
  if (n.entity.key == k)
    Stream(n)
  else
    n.children.toStream.flatMap( findSub(_, k) )
```

Note this isn't tail recursive.  Here's a version which uses a tail recursive helper:

```
def findSub2(n: Node, k: String): Stream[Node] = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def findSubRec(next: Stream[Node], k: String): Stream[Node] =
    next match {
      case h #:: t =>
        if (h.entity.key == k)
          Stream(h)
        else
          findSubRec(h.children.toStream #::: t, k)
      case _ => Stream.empty
    }
  findSubRec(Stream(n), k)
}
```

Sample Scastie: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ZXb7AyJKQ16ldBRG359Utw